# How could I turn off\on dnsmasq?

Tags: network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

**Is there any way to switch on/off dnsmasq?**

Obvious command `systemctl status\start\stop dnsmasq` gives nothing as it seems that `dnsmasq.service` file does not exist.

Question arose as I found in docs that putting dns=dnsmasq in [main] section will make NetworkManager run dnsmasq and update resolv.conf to point to running dnsmasq accordingly. So I want to handcontrol dnsmasq manually(by putting dns=none in NetworkManager.conf) without delegating to NetworkManager.

Thanks.

Comment: I use dnsmasq on my system (ubuntu server 16.04) and `systemctl status dnsmasq` works fine. Have you installed dnsmasq? (sorry if this is patronising) `apt-get install dnsmasq`

Comment: Oh, my mistake, after finding dnsmasq on another box and not remembering installing it, I thought that it is installed by default and didn't even check, sorry wasting your time. Write ans.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that dnsmasq wasn't installed as I assumed that it should be installed by default.

```
apt install dnsmasq
```

solves the problem.